# What's a good way to provide additional decoration/metadata for Python function parameters?

Tags: python

We're considering using Python (IronPython, but I don't think that's relevant) to provide a sort of 'macro' support for another application, which controls a piece of equipment.

We'd like to write fairly simple functions in Python, which take a few arguments - these would be things like times and temperatures and positions.   Different functions would take different arguments, and the main application would contain user interface (something like a property grid) which allows the users to provide values for the Python function arguments.

So, for example function1 might take a time and a temperature, and function2 might take a position and a couple of times.

We'd like to be able to dynamically build the user interface from the Python code.  Things which are easy to do are to find a list of functions in a module, and (using inspect.getargspec) to get a list of arguments to each function.

However, just a list of argument names is not really enough - ideally we'd like to be able to include some more information about each argument - for instance, it's 'type' (high-level type - time, temperature, etc, not language-level type), and perhaps a 'friendly name' or description.

So, the question is, what are good 'pythonic' ways of adding this sort of information to a function.

The two possibilities I have thought of are:

- Use a strict naming convention for arguments, and then infer stuff about them from their names (fetched using getargspec)
- Invent our own docstring meta-language (could be little more than CSV) and use the docstring for our metadata.

Because Python seems pretty popular for building scripting into large apps, I imagine this is a solved problem with some common conventions, but I haven't been able to find them.

Comment: If you were using Python3, you could use function annotations: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/

Comment: The py.test uses the first approach you mention for specifying data for each of the tests. It works fairly well in their case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Decorators are a good way to add metadata to functions. Add one that takes a list of types to append to a .params property or something:

```
def takes(*args):
    def _takes(fcn):
        fcn.params = args
        return fcn
    return _takes

@takes("time", "temp", "time")
def do_stuff(start_time, average_temp, stop_time):
    pass
```

Comment: Consider using objects rather than strings for describing types:
`@takes(Time, Temp, Time)`. Strings are not very good approach because you can't extend that model without modifying core. Also your core can by state-less (you don't have to register type names). Your objects should know how to render itself to HTML and how to validate itself. Also you have benefit that you can parametrize your types:
`@takes(Int(max=100, min=0))`.

Comment: Yes, that. The strings were really just demonstrative. When I did this in the past, I used functions that accepted strings (my only source of input) and returned objects that my program could use (sometimes after doing database lookups).

Answer (score 4):

I would use some kind of decorator:

```
class TypeProtector(object):
    def __init__(self, fun, types):
        self.fun, self.types = fun, types
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        # validate args with self.types
        pass
        # run function
        return fun(*args, **kwargs)

def types(*args):
    def decorator(fun):
        # validate args count with fun parameters count
        pass
        # return covered function
        return TypeProtector(fun, args)
    return decorator

@types(Time, Temperature)
def myfunction(foo, bar):
    pass

myfunction('21:21', '32C')
print myfunction.types
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I wish I could give you all the 'answer'.   Aside from the original question, what's the role of TypeProtector in this?

Comment: ie. you can easily check if function is decorated or not: isinstance(TypeProtector, o). Basically modifying function object directly like in `fcn.params = args` its not so good idea if you want clean self-explainable code.

Answer (score 1):

The 'pythonic' way to do this are [function annotations](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/).

```
def DoSomething(critical_temp: "temperature", time: "time")
    pass
```

Comment: for 2.6, he could use your one

Comment: This was very interesting as it lead me into several useful sources of info - unfortunately I can't use it on this particular project because of the version issue, but I will eventually, I'm sure

Answer (score 0):

For python 2.x, I like to use the docstring

```
def my_func(txt):
    """{
    "name": "Justin",
    "age"   :15
    }"""
    pass
```

and it can be automatically assign to the function object with this snippet

```
for f in globals():
    if not hasattr(globals()[f], '__call__'):
        continue
    try:
        meta = json.loads(globals()[f].__doc__)
    except:
        continue
    for k, v in meta.items():
        setattr(globals()[f], k, v)
```