# How can attributes on functions survive wrapping?

Tags: python, python-decorators

Let's say I have the following function which has an attribute which marks it for special handling within a callback subsystem:

```
def my_func(msg):
    print msg

my_func.my_marker = SPECIAL_CONSTANT
```

The problem is that if other bits of code wrap `my_func` with `functools.partial` or another decorator, then `my_marker` will be lost.

```
my_partial = partial(my_func, 'hello world')
print my_partial.my_marker
>>> AttributeError...
```

Is there a way to protect attributes on functions when wrapping? Is there a better way to store the metadata I'm currently storing in `my_marker`? It seems like storing a reference to the original function suffers from the same problem.

Comment: `my_marker` is not lost. It's still right where you put it, on the original function.

Comment: @kindall -- thanks, though that's not quite what i meant :) The question is really: where should I put function metadata so that decorators, etc. maintain the attribute in wrapped functions?

Comment: What you'd probably want to do is monkey-patch `functools.partial` and/or `functools.wraps` to copy those attributes (or maybe just generically all non-underscore attributes) to the wrapper function.

Answer (score 2):

If you know that the partial you use is actually a partial, you can use it's `func` attribute.

E. g.

```
from functools import partial

SPECIAL_CONSTANT = 'bam'


def my_func(msg):
    print msg

my_func.my_marker = SPECIAL_CONSTANT

my_partial = partial(my_func, 'hello world')

print my_partial.func.my_marker
```

If you really have to handle meta_data, maybe it is a better approach to write classes and override the `__call__()` method.

Comment: Yes, using `__call__()` is probably the thing to do here.

Comment: Sorry, I take that back :( `__call__()` is another attribute in a sense, and also suffers from shadowing when being wrapped.

Comment: @matthewatabet Actually, [obo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3573085/cbo) has the right of it. A custom class defining `__call__()`– as [this answer elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3611121/2809027) demonstrates – is the canonical solution to most function metadata questions. This question is no exception. Since the custom class accepts the decorated function as the first parameter of its `__init__()` method, preserving function attributes trivially reduces to copying those attributes into the current class instance. This is left as an exercise to the reader. **Done.**

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution, using `functools.update_wrapper`.

```
from functools import partial, update_wrapper, WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS


SPECIAL_CONSTANT = 'bam'


def my_func(msg):
    print msg


my_func.my_marker = SPECIAL_CONSTANT

my_partial = partial(my_func, 'hello world')
update_wrapper(my_partial, my_func, WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS + ('my_marker', ))

print my_partial.my_marker
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by kindall's comment, cbo's answer and the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/functools.py):

```
from functools import partial as _partial, update_wrapper

def partial(func, *args, **keywords):
    return update_wrapper(_partial(func, *args, **keywords), func)
```

An example showing it working, and caveats:

```
def my_func(msg):
    print msg


my_func.my_marker = 'FOO'

my_partial = partial(my_func, 'hello world')

print my_func.my_marker
print my_partial.my_marker

# check other stuff is still there
print my_partial.func
print my_partial.args
print my_partial.keywords

# this works fine for READ ONLY stuff.

# so just remember:

my_partial.my_marker = 'BAR' # this _only_ updates partial, not the original

print my_func.my_marker
print my_partial.my_marker


my_func.my_marker = 'BAZ' # this _only_ updates original, not the partial

print my_func.my_marker
print my_partial.my_marker
```

You *can* do something like:

```
import functools
setattr(functools, 'partial', partial) # from above code
```

However, this is probably a **bad idea** as (1) it would need to be imported before any code which relied on it, (2) it could break imported code, (3) it might confuse future people and (4) the alternative, keeping it locally, is easy. Only do this if you want to force third party code to run your version.